# Childrens width set to equal and can't be changed when applying display:table to the parent

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have been looking for a more fixable structure for my navigation. I concluded that using `display:table` is the way to go "for now anyway".

This is my first attempt trying to apply this technique to the way I build my navigation menus. Below is two problems which I couldn't find a workaround for at all. Your help is really appreciated.

**1)** The menu items are all receiving the same width "inherited from the narrowest I presume?" which is breaking the ones which are longer "Longer Item Menu". I can't figure out how to *not* give the menu items an equal width and prevent them from breaking.

[image]

I played around with `table-layout: fixed;` and `border-collapse: collapse;` but to no avail. What am I missing?

**2)** When I tried to introduce dropdown menus to my navigation, things got a little bit messy.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the the menu of the dropdown strictly inhering its width from the parent, which brings us to the same problem as in point 1.

I tried to fix it with overflow, width but again, to no avail.

I have prepared a **Fiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/qqhe1apk/1

Here is the HTML:

```
<header id="header">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="logo">
                <h1>Logo</h1>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="block">
            <nav class="mainMenu">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Index</a></li>
                    <li><a>Modules</a></li>
                    <li><a class="noLink">Dropdown</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Dropdown Longer Text</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a>Dropdown Menu</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>Item 1</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a>Item 1.1</a></li>
                                    <li><a >Item 1.2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Item 2</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a>Item 2.1</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
/*Header*/
    #header {
      background-color: #fff;
      position: relative;
        z-index: 10000;
    }

    /*Header > Quick Commands*/
    #header.headerFixed {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    }

        /*Header > Content Container*/
        #header .content {
          width: 1024px;
          padding: 0 20px;
            margin: 0 auto;
          position: relative;
        }

        /*Header > Content Container > Blocks*/
        #header .content .block {
            width: 100%;
            display: table-cell; 
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            /*Header logo*/
            #header .logo {
              width: 200px;
              margin: 12px 0;
            }

                #header .logo a {
                  display: block;
                }

            /*Header Main Menu*/
            #header .mainMenu {
              display: table; 
              table-layout: fixed;
              border-collapse: collapse;
            }

                #header .mainMenu > ul {
                    display: table-row;
                }

                    #header .mainMenu > ul > li {
                        display: table-cell; 
                        vertical-align: middle;
                        position: relative;
                        height: 100%;
                    }

                        #header .mainMenu ul li a {
                          padding: 10px 15px;
                        }

                        #header .mainMenu ul li a:hover {
                          color: #3764B2;
                        }

                        #header .mainMenu ul li a.active, 
                        #header .mainMenu ul li a.active:hover {
                          color: #fff;
                          background-color: #3764B2;
                            cursor: default !important;
                        }

                        /*Header Main Menu > Dropdowns*/
                        #header .mainMenu ul ul {
                            background-color: #fff;
                          position: absolute; 
                          top: 100%; left: 0;
                          text-align: left;
                          display: none;
                        }

                        #header .mainMenu li:hover > ul {
                            display: block;
                        }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li {

                            }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li a {
                              display: inline-block;
                              border-radius: 0;
                            }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li a:hover {
                              color: #3764B2;
                              background-color: #F2F2F2;
                            }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li a.active, 
                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li a.active:hover {
                              color: #fff;
                              background-color: #3764B2;
                            }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul li:hover > a {
                              color: #3764B2 !important;
                            }

                            #header .mainMenu ul ul:hover > a.active {
                              color: #fff;
                            }

                                /*Header Main Menu > Dropdowns > Second Level Dropdowns*/
                                #header .mainMenu ul ul ul {
                                  top: 0; left: 100%;
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a min width on your sub menus, and add `display:inline-block;`

**DEMO**

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.topMenu {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: gray;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.6s;
}
.topMenu:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
.sub {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 200%;
  display: none;
}
.topMenu:hover .sub {
  display: block;}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="topMenu">Menu Item</div>
  <div class="topMenu">Menu Item</div>
  <div class="topMenu">Menu Item</div>
  <div class="topMenu">Longer Menu Item
    <div class="sub">
      <div class="topMenu">Longer Menu Item</div>
      <div class="topMenu">Even Longer Menu Item</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="topMenu">Menu Item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I need it to stay as display:table if can.

Comment: So I can stretch the menu across the width of the header mate

Comment: that's why i've included the width of the nav? to take 100% of relative parent's width? @Leo

Comment: The menu items are not stretching though @jbutler483

Comment: @Leo: could you explain? (not quite sure I quite understand you). What's not stretching? Could you edit your post to include this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73036/discussion-between-leo-and-jbutler483).